# Fixing Docker "build from" failure on repo (insufficient_scope: authorization failed) where "docker pull" (of JBPM) succeeds

Tags: docker, dockerfile, jbpm

Trying my first-ever "docker build" I am seeing:

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

I can get the image with docker pull:

```
PS C:\Users\dr_cl\Desktop\ams-pam> docker pull jboss/jbpm-server-full:7.48.0.Final
7.48.0.Final: Pulling from jboss/jbpm-server-full
a02a4930cb5d: Pull complete
b5ffff9dbcda: Pull complete
...
Digest: sha256:65884b407c1922ee74b829ed7e138ce8a7ebbbabe4d3ff157e09d9939c69295c...
```

I am logged in to Docker Hub so how do I correct this - the only non-commented out line in my - Dockerfile - from failing (and why)?

```
FROM jbpm-server-full@sha256:65884b407c1922ee74b829ed7e138ce8a7ebbbabe4d3ff157e09d9939c69295c as jbpm
```

Comment: It can't find the repo.  You need to use the full repository name, e.g. "jboss/jbpm-server-full" not just "jbpm-server-full".